# How to convert dynamically in C# the parsed JSON result from Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json.net, type-conversion, json-rpc

I have implemented a JSON-RPC with Json.NET. The result of the response I convert with:

```
T data = ((JToken)value).ToObject<T>();
```

This work if the result is an object. But it does not work if the result is an primitive like Int64 or an string. Then the value is not a JToken.

I have found the method:

```
static object Convert(object initialValue, CultureInfo culture, Type targetType)
```

which seems to do the needed job. But the class ConvertUtils is internal. It there any public method to convert any parsed JSON result to any target type?

A more completely sample with the JSON-RPC handling:

```
JsonRpcResult result = serializer.Deserialize<JsonRpcResult>(jsonTextReader);
Type type = requests[result.id];
object value = result.result;
return ((JToken)value).ToObject(type);
```

A typical JSON string:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":DynamicValidJsonDependsOnID,"id":1}
```

The JSON content of DynamicValidJsonDependsOnID depends on the id and can be any valid JSON. There are no limits.

The class JsonRpcResult:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.Fields)]
internal class JsonRpcResult
{
    private string jsonrpc;
    private object result;
    private Dictionary<String,Object> error;
    private object id;
 }
```

Comment: what about using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(string json)`

Comment: Not sure I understand your requirements.  Are you looking for [`Convert.ChangeType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @IswarKChettri The JSON is already parsed and I have already a JObject. But is can also an Int64 or null. See the more detailed sample. I can convert the result after it completely parsed because I need the "id" of the response  first.

Comment: @dbc Yes, I search some things but it must also convert a JObject, JArray and all what the json parser can return.

Comment: @Horcrux7 - can't you just check `if (value is JToken)` and, if so, use `ToObject()`, but if not, use `Convert.ChangeType()`?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong.. that you are trying to get id from json and you are not been able to parse jsonRpc to json which is dynamic. right?

Comment: @IswarKChettri The JSON look like: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":DynamicDependsOnID,"id":1}

Comment: @dbc This will be only a partial solution. The code in Json.NET for converting has multiple hundred line of code. For example string to byte[] via base64.

Comment: @Horcrux7 - in that case can you provide a [mcve] showing the JSON file(s) you want to parse and how you want to parse them?

Comment: @Horcrux7 is it possible to change your json's structure now, or you are restricted to use it as it is?

Comment: @Horcrux7 is DynamicValidJsonDependsOnID  a class?

Answer (score 2):

When you deserialize your `JsonRpcResult` object, your `object result` field will either be a complex object or a primitive type.

So if it's a primitive type (ex. `Int32`), `result.result` will contain the direct value instead of a `JToken`

So, I would first check if the `Type` is primitive or not like this:

```
JsonRpcResult result = serializer.Deserialize<JsonRpcResult>(jsonTextReader);
Type type = requests[result.id];
object value = result.result;

if (!type.IsPrimitive && type != typeof(decimal) && type != typeof(string) && type != typeof(DateTime))
    return ((JToken)value).ToObject(type);
return value; //otherwise return the value as it is without parsing.
```

**EDIT**

As you are getting the `Type`s on runtime, you **can't** cast the your `object`s to the correct `Type` as it is. You have to use the `dynamic` keyword as mentioned in other answers too, or check if the object's Type is the type you want and cast it like this:

```
if (type == typeof(string))
{
    string str = (string)returnedValue;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Newtonsoft.Json.Jobject.Parse` like this

```
 //==== Create class for your Json attributes
 string jsonData= " { \"Employee":{\"name\":\"John\", \"age\":31, \"city\":\"New York\" }}";
 YourJsonClass obj= new YourJsonClass();
 var jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonData);
 obj= jObject["Employee"].ToObject<YourJsonClass>();
```

Your `YourJsonClass` would be

```
 public class YourJsonClass
 {
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string city{ get; set; }
 }
```

You can access through `obj` like this:

```
 string name =obj.name;
 int age=obj.age;
 string city=obj.city;
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This is like my code. It fire an exception if YourJsonClass is an Int32, a string or any other JSON prinimtive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword "dynamic" instead of hard-coded type, so it will resole the type for you.
Please take a look at this tutorial:

[tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic)

Comment: The problem is the converting of the parsed object. The dynamic type does not solve the class cast errors at runtime.